# Algorithm to convert real numbers decimal to binary

Tags: algorithm, binary

Currently trying to write code that converts decimal floats to binary base form (I know BaseForm exists).

Currently I'm working with an example that takes 3.3 and converts it:

```
binary={}
x = Floor[3.3*2^8];
For[i = 0, i <= 9, i++,
  remainder = Mod[x, 2];
  x = Floor[x/2];
  AppendTo[binary, remainder];
  ];
Print[FromDigits[Reverse[binary]]]
```

Which gives:
`1101001100`

Obviously the answer should have a . between 11 and 01001100, but I'm not quite sure how to implement this. Does anyone have any ideas (so it would work with all examples, not just 3.3).

Thanks!

Comment: `RealDigits[3.3, 2]` and you can control the number of digits you want with the 3rd argument?

Comment: `BaseForm[3.3, 2]`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want just a string representing real num base2, extract the base-2 digits and base-2 exponent of the form {{digits},exponent} and then convert it to a string:

```
 myNum = 41.213;
    myB = RealDigits[myNum, 2]
    myBExp = myB[[2]]
    newFormat = 
     ToString@Row[myB[[1, 1 ;; myBExp]]] <> "." <> 
      ToString@Row[myB[[1, myBExp + 1 ;;]]]
```

Out[704]= {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 6}

Out[706]= "101001.00110110100001110010101100000010000011000100101"

Comment: Or `ToString@Row@Insert[#1, ".", #2 + 1] & @@ RealDigits[#, 2] &[41.213]`.

Comment: Please try your code with `myNum=0.213`.

Comment: Ok.  I'll leave that for you:  Put an If statement in.  If the exponent "myBExp" is negative (or zero?), then string together a "0" a "." then a total of  Abs[myBExp] zeros, then add all the remaining digits of myB[[1]].  Something like leadingZeros=Table[0,{Abs[myBExp]]].  Then newFormat="0"<>"."<>ToString@Row[leadingZeros]<>ToString@Row[myB[[1]]].  You may have to work with it a bit to work with all possible cases including negative numbers.